# Is there a client-side iOS 14 method that provides the app or web install referrer?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ios14, install-referrer

I want to understand where my users came from (another app, website, paid advertisement, etc).

Their journey would be something like: viewing a website X containing an ad Y to my app -> clicking the ad -> app product page opens up in the iOS AppStore -> click 'install' -> launch my app.

I am interested in the identities of "website X" and "ad Y" parts of the journey.

This data is available on Apple's system - AppStore Connect - but I want to know the referring app/website/ad in runtime.

Also, there are 3rd systems that create the links for me and provide some of this info, like Kochava and Adjust, but I can't use them for my tiny app.

Numerous threads on SO discuss this issue, but all of them conclude it's impossible in iOS (compared to the Google Play Store). Also, these thread do not relate specifically to getting the install referrer in the iOS client-side, on runtime.

Thank you in advance!